# Error reporting on jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

this maybe seems a bit silly, but how can i get an error report when using AJAX with jquery?

This is my code

```
url: "ajax/jquery_email.php",
                                                type: "POST",
                                                data: "email="+email+"&conteudo="+conteudo,
                                                success: function()
                                                    {
                                                        alert("successo");
                                                        $("#val_email_conf").html('email enviado');
                                                    },
                                                error:function()
                                                    {
                                                          alert("erro");
                                                          $("#val_email_conf").html('email nao enviado');
                                                    }
```

But i want the complete error report, because i don't know what is wrong with it (not working, not sure if it is not finding the file) so i need to see the error report for it.

Thanks and sorry guys.

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: Goddammit, i knew it was a stupid question of mine, completely forgot about the console, it is showing an 404 on my jquery_email.php ... Thanks you very much, i think i just found the problem.

Comment: Just leave the console open whenever you are doing JavaScript work. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation again for [jQuery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  You can actually receive arguments inside the `error` function (as well as the `success` function).  You can name them whatever you want, but in the documentation they're defined as `jqXHR` (The jQuery XHR object), `textStatus` (string), and `errorThrown`.  Use these to better help diagnose issues you're running into if the problem isn't apparent from the console.

Admittedly, though, these offer only limited help.